# r.watershed error in QGIS (3.16.2) for MAC

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, r.watershed

I'm trying to use the r.watershed tool, here is the error that is arising. I've tried changing the GRASS path to custom /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/grass78 and it doesn't seem to work either. Does someone know what might be wrong?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Here are the screenshots of the log panel:
[image: plugin]
[image: processing]
[image: general]
[image: grass]

> QGIS version: 3.16.2-Hannover QGIS code revision: c6ac5a6052 Qt
> version: 5.14.2 GDAL version: 3.1.2 GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
> PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020 Processing algorithm…
> Algorithm 'r.watershed' starting… Input parameters: { '-4' : False,
> '-a' : False, '-b' : False, '-m' : False, '-s' : False,
> 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '',
> 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' :
> None, 'accumulation' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'basin' :
> 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'blocking' : None, 'convergence' : 5, 'depression'
> : None, 'disturbed_land' : None, 'drainage' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
> 'elevation' :
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/b7ea5fc72b014cb39e1d9b62fb1cca60/OUTPUT.tif',
> 'flow' : None, 'half_basin' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'length_slope' :
> 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'max_slope_length' : None, 'memory' : 300,
> 'slope_steepness' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'spi' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
> 'stream' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'tci' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold'
> : 10000 }
>
> g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
> r.in.gdal
> input="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/b7ea5fc72b014cb39e1d9b62fb1cca60/OUTPUT.tif"
> band=1 output="rast_5ffee631ef5947" --overwrite -o g.region
> n=5220505.94804144 s=4997005.94804144 e=761957.64997435
> w=605957.64997435 res=100.0 r.watershed elevation=rast_5ffee631ef5947
> threshold=10000 convergence=5 memory=300
> accumulation=accumulationa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> drainage=drainagea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> basin=basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> stream=streama7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> half_basin=half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> length_slope=length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> slope_steepness=slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> tci=tcia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53
> spi=spia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 --overwrite g.region
> raster=accumulationa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="accumulationa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2f1a07d3617e422f8ada83f1c31be861/accumulation.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=drainagea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="drainagea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/146e832478954e80910f965cfece799e/drainage.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/4114f2a8049e4999aa119afeedbf5fa8/basin.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=streama7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="streama7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/57b019cca54a4b4cb97b7dc7f932a7af/stream.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/188f626da9f94d3a90350688ea633db7/half_basin.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2a6f0900f6424a4298179cf967b520b4/length_slope.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t
> -m input="slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53" output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/73f4c1e80722461fba1087e6ad17e997/slope_steepness.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=tcia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="tcia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/74e539c6455d4ccd92f3baadd92dc31e/tci.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite g.region
> raster=spia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53 r.out.gdal -t -m
> input="spia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53"
> output="/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/9341f608a39248628203df1630046f77/spi.tif"
> format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite Default
> locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale. Starting
> GRASS GIS... Cleaning up temporary files... Executing
> </private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh>
> ... Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have
> multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the
> region from the default Projection information updated Over-riding
> projection check Importing raster map <rast_5ffee631ef5947>...
> 0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgrass_raster.7.8.dylib Referenced
> from:
> /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/grass78/etc/r.watershed/ram
> Reason: image not found WARNING: Subprocess failed with exit code 6
> WARNING: category information for
> [accumulationa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing
> or invalid WARNING: category information for
> [tcia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [spia7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [drainagea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [streama7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing or
> invalid WARNING: category information for
> [length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT] missing
> or invalid WARNING: category information for
> [slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53] in [PERMANENT]
> missing or invalid ERROR: Raster map
>  not found ERROR: Raster
> map or group  not found
> ERROR: Raster map  not found
> ERROR: Raster map or group 
> not found ERROR: Raster map 
> not found ERROR: Raster map or group
>  not found ERROR: Raster map
>  not found ERROR: Raster map
> or group  not found ERROR:
> Raster map <half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found
> ERROR: Raster map or group
> <half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR: Raster
> map <length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR:
> Raster map or group <length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not
> found ERROR: Raster map
> <slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR:
> Raster map or group <slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53>
> not found ERROR: Raster map  not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group 
> not found ERROR: Raster map  not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group 
> not found Execution of
> </private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh>
> finished. Cleaning up default sqlite database ... Cleaning up
> temporary files... Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running
> with C locale. Starting GRASS GIS... Cleaning up temporary files...
> Executing
> </private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh>
> ... ERROR: Raster map 
> not found ERROR: Raster map or group
>  not found ERROR: Raster
> map  not found ERROR: Raster
> map or group  not found
> ERROR: Raster map  not found
> ERROR: Raster map or group  not
> found ERROR: Raster map  not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group
>  not found ERROR: Raster map
> <half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR: Raster
> map or group <half_basina7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found
> ERROR: Raster map <length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group
> <length_slopea7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR: Raster
> map <slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53> not found ERROR:
> Raster map or group <slope_steepnessa7ae7bf7f2954266a3ed4260e3ef8e53>
> not found ERROR: Raster map  not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group 
> not found ERROR: Raster map  not
> found ERROR: Raster map or group 
> not found Execution of
> </private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/grassdata/grass_batch_job.sh>
> finished. Cleaning up default sqlite database ... Cleaning up
> temporary files... Execution completed in 4.78 seconds Results:
> {'accumulation':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2f1a07d3617e422f8ada83f1c31be861/accumulation.tif',
> 'basin':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/4114f2a8049e4999aa119afeedbf5fa8/basin.tif',
> 'drainage':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/146e832478954e80910f965cfece799e/drainage.tif',
> 'half_basin':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/188f626da9f94d3a90350688ea633db7/half_basin.tif',
> 'length_slope':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2a6f0900f6424a4298179cf967b520b4/length_slope.tif',
> 'slope_steepness':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/73f4c1e80722461fba1087e6ad17e997/slope_steepness.tif',
> 'spi':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/9341f608a39248628203df1630046f77/spi.tif',
> 'stream':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/57b019cca54a4b4cb97b7dc7f932a7af/stream.tif',
> 'tci':
> '/private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/74e539c6455d4ccd92f3baadd92dc31e/tci.tif'}
>
> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
> generated. •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/146e832478954e80910f965cfece799e/drainage.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/188f626da9f94d3a90350688ea633db7/half_basin.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2a6f0900f6424a4298179cf967b520b4/length_slope.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/2f1a07d3617e422f8ada83f1c31be861/accumulation.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/4114f2a8049e4999aa119afeedbf5fa8/basin.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/57b019cca54a4b4cb97b7dc7f932a7af/stream.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/73f4c1e80722461fba1087e6ad17e997/slope_steepness.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/74e539c6455d4ccd92f3baadd92dc31e/tci.tif
> •
> /private/var/folders/rd/wzfh_5h110l121rmlxn61v440000gn/T/processing_yomvoy/9341f608a39248628203df1630046f77/spi.tif
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
> more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: What does the "log messages panel" say? Had you set a threshold?

Comment: Yes, I have set it and it still gives me the same error. The log message panel says basically the same as what I posted in the question. I'm adding a screenshot of the log panel

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the r.watershed for MacOs and the team will work on it according to what they told me in my GitHub report. Here is the thread  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40996